# Overlaying WMS in custom coordinate system with other layers in openlayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, coordinate-system

I have a raster in a custom coordinate system (I added the coordinate system definition to the geoserver EPSG file so that I could choose it as the native projection. Now I would like to add it to a map in openlayers 3, however I can't seem to get it to show up. I was trying to use the code in this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/wms-custom-proj.html but so far I can't get it to show. This is the code for my WMS layer I want to add:

```
var countyAerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [2422100,574699.9999999,2565500,781299.9999999998],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://107.182.235.75:8080/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'IDAda:county_aerial', 'TILED': true},
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
  });
```

I want to transform this into EPSG 3857 and am not sure the code in the example will work for me, I don't completely understand it. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the request sent to GeoServer? Does this request work in the browser? How is your map set up? does it work if you use a W<S layer instead of tiles? does your layer work in GeoServer's preview?

Comment: What is the source projection???? Does it have an official EPSG code. Your geoserver serves it with srs=EPSG:10000000. What is the definition of this projection?

Comment: I added the EPSG code 1000000 to geoserver it's a custom projection. Interestingly, I removed the extent when declaring the tile layer variable (shown above) and now it shows up on the map.